# need help fixing a small method in a class

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I am not sure why this is not working, the logic looks fine to me. I would love a more experienced eye to maybe offer some advice. This should return `_grit` to be `1`. but it returns `0`. and if I make `gainedToughness(8)`, `_grit` returns `4` and it should return `3`.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, profession){
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._profession = profession;
        this._health = 100;
        this._grit = 0;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
    get profession() {
        return this._profession;
    }
    gotInjured(damageNum){
        const weaker = this._health -= damageNum;
        return weaker;
    }
    gainedToughness(damageNum){.           <---------------------------
        let grittier = this._grit++;
        let lotGrittier = this._grit += 3;
        return damageNum <= 5 ? grittier : lotGrittier; 
    }
}

const donRickles = new Person('donRickles', 33, 'comedian');

console.log(donRickles.gotInjured(1));
console.log(donRickles.gainedToughness(1));      <-----------
```

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed

Comment: `++` should be `+ 1`, `+=` should be `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `++` and `+=` were causing your problems. Since they are both designed for reassignment of the variable, and that's not what you want.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, profession){
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._profession = profession;
        this._health = 100;
        this._grit = 0;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
    get profession() {
        return this._profession;
    }
    gotInjured(damageNum){
        const weaker = this._health -= damageNum;
        return weaker;
    }
    gainedToughness(damageNum){
        let grittier = this._grit + 1;
        let lotGrittier = this._grit + 3;
        return damageNum <= 5 ? grittier : lotGrittier; 
    }
}

const donRickles = new Person('donRickles', 33, 'comedian');

console.log(donRickles.gotInjured(1));
console.log(donRickles.gainedToughness(1));
console.log(donRickles.gainedToughness(8));
```

If you want to update the values of your properties as well as return the new value, do this:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, profession){
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._profession = profession;
        this._health = 100;
        this._grit = 0;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
    get profession() {
        return this._profession;
    }
    gotInjured(damageNum){
        const weaker = this._health - damageNum;
        this._health = weaker;
        return this._health;
    }
    gainedToughness(damageNum){
        let grittier = this._grit + 1;
        let lotGrittier = this._grit + 3;
        this._grit = damageNum <= 5 ? grittier : lotGrittier; 
        return this._grit;
    }
}

const donRickles = new Person('donRickles', 33, 'comedian');

console.log(donRickles._health)
console.log(donRickles.gotInjured(1));
console.log(donRickles._health)

console.log(donRickles._grit)
console.log(donRickles.gainedToughness(1));
console.log(donRickles._grit)
```

Comment: Edited to include option for updating the values of your properties AND return them.

Comment: if I wanted to simultaneously reduce health but add grit, would I have to put another function inside of ```gotInjured```?  I was trying to return two values but didn't know how to do that.

Comment: generally speaking you can return two values as an array (numbered list) or an object (named list) however maybe I should start by asking why you are interested in returning the value. It's common for logic to be separated into getters and setters, in other words one method will "set" the value of a prop and another method will "get" or return it. If you wanted to update two props at once you could create a method like `setAandB(a, b)` that calls `setA(a)` and `setB(b)` inside it. To get the values back you could call a method like `getAandB()` which returns an object `{a: this.a, b: this.b}`